# Autoupdate Drop down menu, when a data validation cell content is changed (Google Sheets)

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have a list of values for example {A, B, C}, and then a drop drown menu which is dependent on the list of values I just shared! So in the drop-down menu, I can choose A, B, or C!
Assuming I have chosen the value C for a bunch of drop-down cells I have created, and then I change the value C in the list of values to something like K i.e. my new list of values becomes {A, B, K}! Why doesn't my bunch of values that I had chosen to be C automatically change to K! Is there a way to automatically update them all, where I have chosen the corresponding C value from the drop-down?

Comment: you will need a refresh script for this

Comment: So there is no way to do it with any inbuilt functions in sheets?

Comment: unfortunately nope

Comment: How are you changing the values? Are they defined in some cells?

Comment: I just have a separate tab, where I have listed these values {A, B, C}. And then I have another tab, where I use data validation over these listed values so that I can have them in form of a drop-down menu!

Answer (score 1):

To replace a value you can use `TextFinder`:

```
function changeOptions(target, search, replaceWith) {
  target
    .createTextFinder(search)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .replaceAllWith(replaceWith)
}
```

You can combine this with `onEdit(e)`. First get the necessary data:

```
  const { source, range, oldValue, value } = e
```

Stop the function if the edit is not on the options page or the edited value was empty or it has been removed:

```
  if (!oldValue || !value || range.getSheet().getName() !== OPTIONS_SHEET_NAME)
    return
```

And finally do the replace:

```
  const target = source.getRange(VALIDATED_RANGE)
  changeOptions(target, oldValue, value)
```

`OPTIONS_SHEET_NAME` is the name of the sheet with the options. `VALIDATED_RANGE` must be a fully an A1 range with the sheet (for example `Values!A1:A`).

Also, you may need to modify it for your needs.

### References

- [Spreadsheet.getRange(a1Notation) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [Range.createTextFinder(findText) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [Spreadsheet onEdit event object (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Was this useful? Do you have any question?

Comment: I was looking for a way to update data validation like this and came across this old post. Martí your solution is excellent--thank you!